# predicate filter rxjava2 - How to pass dynamic filter arguments

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have built some basic filter with rxjava2 which works as expected. I was wondering how I could pass values/pass arguments to the filter `(return td.getTypeId() == **<value>**;)`.  Also if somebody has ideas/clues/examples on how to build a (semi-)dynamic query (`Object.<field> == <value>`) with rxjava2 / filter that would be appreciated.

```
Predicate<TradeDetailed> testfilter;

Flowable<List<TradeDetailed>> td = tr.getTradesDetailedFlowable();

testfilter = new Predicate<TradeDetailed>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(@NonNull TradeDetailed td) throws Exception {
        return td.getTypeId() == 0;
    }
};

Disposable d = td
        .flatMapIterable(e -> e)
        .filter(e-> testfilter.test(e))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(t -> {
                        System.out.println("filtered "+t.getReference()));

                    },
                    err -> {
                        System.out.println("error");
                    }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a separate class for the `Predicate`:

```
class YourPredicate implements Predicate<TradeDetailed>(){

    private final int compareAgainst;

    public YourPredicate(int compareAgainst){
        this.compareAgainst = compareAgainst;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(@NonNull TradeDetailed td) throws Exception {
        return td.getTypeId() == compareAgainst;
    }

}
```